# What does 'exclude rows that do not contain values' checkbox do in SQL Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I want to filter a trace and wonder what does  'exclude rows that do not contain values' checkbox exactly do? Is it to filter all the data columns that are not selected in any event class?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically this

```
WHERE .. AND TheValue NOT NULL
```

Like/Not like filters only works on values that exist for **that** event.
No value is always true and passes the filter: this checkbox removes that

For example:

- You want to see SQL:BatchStarting events
- You filter on Duration

Duration is not valid for SQL:BatchStarting, so the filter is ignored

Comment: Thanks, actually I have one question, if Duration is not valid for SQL:BatchStarting event, if I set a filter on Duration and do not check 'exclude rows that do not contain values' checkbox, isn't it going to be ignored anyway?

Comment: No, the filter would always be true. Which makes sense, in one way: don't filter on something that can't be filtered. This checkbox lets you change that

Comment: And if I check the box, how is it going to filter Duration for SQL:BatchStarting if that event does not have Duration tracing available?

Comment: @EleonoraGrigoryan because other events you filter (SQL:BatchCompleted) might have Duration. I've almost never filtered to one Event type